# Can I use ternary operators to handle errors in a promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Is something like this:

```
function gets3Objects(eventsArray) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
      err
        ? reject(err)
        : resolve(eventsArray.forEach((file) => {
          params.Key = file;
        }));
    });
  });
}
```

Considered good practice?
If not, what would be a better alternative to error handling in a javascript promise?

Comment: It's good practice

Comment: it is, but your `eventsArray.forEach` returns `undefined`, is it what you want to do? also write on `params`?

Comment: I personal like `if (err) return reject(err);` as the first line, as this the gets the error logic out the way..

Comment: If you're talking about *good practice*, you can use the `.promise()` function of the AWS SDK instead and that would solve the whole issue. Otherwise, I'm with Keith on this, although I am usually `if(err) reject(); return;`

Comment: @codingIntrigue than you need `{...}` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can*, but you shouldn't. Ternary operators are for when you need an *expression* - when you need to store or assign the result to something. Otherwise, like here, you should use ordinary `if`/`else` statements.

(This being a Promise has nothing to do with the appropriateness of a ternary operator)

Comment: it is okay, because he's using it to resolve/reject a promise

Comment: If the promise was resolvable by evaluating an expression and calling/assigning the result to something, it would be appropriate, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Hitmands  The question was, is it good practice, not if it works in this case.  I would say its bad..